# CSS :hover affecting all list items

Tags: css, hover

I was trying to build a menu for a website, and I used this code:

```
nav#menu:hover li{
    background-color: #606060;
}
```

However, when I hover over the list items on the site, the code changes the background color of every single one of them, not just the one I have my cursor on, does anybody know what I should do?

Comment: Kindly add your html and css minimal snippet only.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it

```
nav#menu li:hover { background-color: #606060; }
```

You had hover on entire menu and not its individual li tags.